# Installing SQL server 2008R2/2012 on windows server 2012 box

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, installation

we are trying to install SQL2k8R2 and SQL server 2012(Standard edition) on the windows server 2012 box (Standard 64 Bit).

For SQL 2k8r2, i used slipstream method so as to bring set up to atleast SP1 for support as compatibility on windows 2k12.

But the problem comes when we are running the set up, i.e. SQL2k8R2 and even SQL2012 , we are getting the below error for missing .Net 3.5

[image]

If we try to enable 3.5 manually from roles and features, we get the below erro

[image]

I've read on many articles, that we need to have the set up for windows to find the required source files for 3.5 for this to proceed. But before going to the team who actually set up the box, is there something we may be missing here and any action or alternative that can be given a try?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you read https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2681562 did you made sure you followed all recommendations

Comment: Yes @Shanky, i went through that and got it resolved. Thanks for you're help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used option 2 from [this](http://www.danielclasson.com/install-net-framework-35-server-2012/) article many times to fix this issue.

Basically insert the windows install disk, enable the .net 3 feature but select the option to 'specify an alternate path' at the end of the wizard. The different path should be D:\sources\sxs (if the disc is in your D drive)

Comment: i tried that but the problem is there is no such mount image or path with the software files as required and mentioned in the article :(

Comment: I thonk you will have to kick it back to your sysadmin then

Comment: Thanks @James, i thought so, but wanted to know if someone has an alternative before i go to server admin as its a long route process and takes quite a time..

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using PowerShell fairly quickly. If you mount the ISO or insert the media for the version of Window Server 2012 you are running, then use the following commands in an PowerShell prompt (elevated privileges required so open it "As administrator":

```
# have to import the module for the cmdlets
Import-Module servermanager

# you can verify it is already installed
(Get-WindowsFeature Net-Framework-Core).Installed

#Install it, using the drive letter of your media
Install-WindowsFeature Net-Framework-Core -source '<drive letter>:\sources\sxs'
```

Once that is finished you should get some output that shows it was successful or not. Overall should look something like this:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Because i am not allowed to comment i write this here.

To install net framework 3.5 you need to be connected to internet. Im assuming you are ?

For more info check this link:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2734782

Comment: Read that KB article fully and you will find that Internet is not required to install this component.